# (ScrollMagic) ERROR: Element defined in option "triggerElement" was not found: .my-element

Tags: javascript, scrollmagic

I have a small problem with scrollMagic plugin.
I'm trying to make simple js and it works fine,
but when I follow to another page here comes an error, I can't understand:

```
18:27:48:554 (ScrollMagic.Scene) -> ERROR: Element defined in option "triggerElement" was not found: .my-element
```

I understand that on this page plugin won't find this element, but it shouldn't work so.
My code (I'm also using TweenMax):

```
var titleParallaxScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '.my-element',
    triggerHook: 0,
    duration: '100%'
})
.setTween(TweenMax.to('.my-title', 0.5, {autoAlpha: 0, y: '250px', ease:Linear.easeNone}))
.addTo(controller);
```

I'm a newbie, so if it is silly question, sorry!
Thanks.

Comment: is there in your page an element with class="my-element"

Comment: I think I explained too bad. I have two pages, call them homepage and about. In about page I have div with class my-element, but haven't in homepage. So when I on about page scroll magic works fine and there is no error, when I follow to homepage I get this error.

Comment: if so, wrap your `var titleParallaxScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '.my-element',
    triggerHook: 0,
    duration: '100%'
})` in a if statment. check `if(document.getElementByClassName('my-element').length > 0){..... your scrollmagic initializazion ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is a good practice check if the element is defined in page before initialize animations
so you have to wrap your code in a if statement

```
if(document.getElementByClassName('my-element').length > 0){
    var titleParallaxScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '.my-element',
        triggerHook: 0,
        duration: '100%'
    })
    .setTween(TweenMax.to('.my-title', 0.5, {autoAlpha: 0, y: '250px', ease:Linear.easeNone}))
    .addTo(controller);
}
```

this made your ScrollMagic fires only if the target element is defined

Comment: Thanks! Now I haven't any errors and everything working fine!